# bash script for switching sound devices

Tags: bash, ubuntu, audio

have speakers and headphones, I want to bind a key to switch between the sound devices. And I would like without having to install additional packages and other programs, because everything you need is already there. Writing

```
#!/bin/bash

# array names sound devices [1]
declare -a SINKS=(
    "<alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>"
    "<alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc...>"
)

# I am going to poll states to interrogate them and to put here
declare -a STATES

# request a lot of information about all sound devices
# and reduces it with grep [2]
IFS=$'\n\t'
STATE=$(pacmd list-sinks | egrep "name:|state:")

# now defines STATES array
for line in ${STATE[@]}; do
  # break lines to key and value [3]
  key=$(echo $line | awk -F ': ' '{print $1}')
  value=$(echo $line | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}')

  if [ "$key" == "name" ]; then
    LAST_KEY="$value"
  fi

  if [ "$key" == "state" ]; then
    # here error message (see below) [4]
    STATES[$LAST_KEY]=$value
  fi

done

echo $STATES
```

The result is a blank line. My brain is accustomed to javascript, flatly refuses to understand this scribbling. I would be very grateful to anyone who can help.

**Variables states**

[1] It's all good

```
<alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo> <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
```

[2] and here

```
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
state: SUSPENDED
name: <alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
state: SUSPENDED
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
state: RUNNING
```

[3] and here (echo "$key::$value")

```
name::<alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
state::SUSPENDED
name::<alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo>
state::SUSPENDED
name::<alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
state::RUNNING
```

[4] error, it seems to me that the cycle is interrupted

```
line 21: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>")
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: btw you shouldn't have a variable named `STATE` and another named `STATES`. It's quite error-prone, and can lead to silly bugs caused by a typo